# javascript copy multiple objects and increment indexes sequentially

Tags: javascript

I have two objects

```
one: 
0: { active: {...}, inactive: {...},
1: { active: {...}, inactive: {...},
two:
0: { active: {...}, inactive: {...},
1: { active: {...}, inactive: {...},
```

I need to combine these into one object and have the indexes incremented sequentially, `0 , 1 , 2 , 3`.

I've tried

```
const combo = [...Object.entries(one), ...Object.entries(two)];
```

But I get indexes `0 , 1 , 0 , 1`

If I try

```
const combo = [...one, ...two]
```

Does not seem to do anything.

I've also tried doing it via `Object.assign({}, one, two)` , however this also didn't do anything.

I need to end up with something I can iterate over using a `for [i, obj] of`, hence spreading into array.

Is there a way I can accomplish what I'm after in a similar type of concat operation, or some kind of workaround that will fix the indexes for me?

Comment: Do you want an object or array as output? You're spreading the entries inside `[]`

Comment: you're right I've added a comment that I need to iterate over them hence spreading like that

Comment: What do you mean “merged instead of concatenated”? `[...one, ...two]` shouldn’t even work on non-iterable objects. Also, why do you have objects with sequential integer indexes starting at 0 instead of arrays? `[...Object.values(one), ...Object.values(two)]` may or may not be right.

Comment: @Ry- right also, fixed comment - this did not work but I thought they had merged

Comment: To iterate over the result, you could use `combo.forEach((obj, i) => { … })` or `for (const [i, obj] of combo.entries()) { … }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is merging into array, use `Object.values` instead.

```js
one = {0: {_ : '1.1' }, 1: {_ : '1.2'}}
two = {0: {_ : '2.1' }, 1: {_ : '2.2'}}

combo = [...Object.values(one), ...Object.values(two)]

combo.forEach((v,i) => {
  console.log(i, v)
})
```

Comment: I've added another comment - I was trying `entries` so I can use `for of` with index - doing it using `values` doesn't seem to give me access to the index in the `for ` loop, I guess I can add counter myself for index

Comment: yes I think this is simplest solution and I can use a simple manual counter, thanks

Comment: I don't think you need add manual counter, just `forEach` method would work. I've update my post.

Comment: thanks - just used to using `for .. of` but you're right

Answer (score 1):

If you want create an array, you can merge the `Object.values()` of both objects. If you want an object with consecutive numerical keys, then spread the merged array inside `{}` brackets. This creates an object with indexes of merged array as keys

```js
const o1={0:{active:{},inactive:{}},1:{active:{},inactive:{}}},
      o2={0:{active:{},inactive:{},},1:{active:{},inactive:{}}}

const mergedArray = [...Object.values(o1), ...Object.values(o2)]
const mergedObject = {...mergedArray };

console.log(mergedArray)
console.log(mergedObject)
```